# App Crashs on Touch of the screen Scenekit with a overlayskscene Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

Hey ok what is the best way to recognize touch for a HUD on a scene kit 3D game on a Overlayskscene. because i have a button called "AButton" but when ever i touch the Button or the screen the game crashes after hours of search I'm guessing the problem is the touchbegin on the scene kit don't exactly get along. But then how do i make it so that when a user touches a button on the HUD it doesn't crash the system and it actually works. can you look at my code and rewrite it. do i use touches begin or do i us hit test or something else (I never have used hit test before)?

handleTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d547710'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1868042d8 0x1980300e4

Code:

```
 import iAd
 import UIKit
 import GameKit
 import SceneKit
 import StoreKit
 import SpriteKit
 import QuartzCore
 import Foundation
 import AVFoundation
 import AudioToolbox

  //============================================================
 class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, SKSceneDelegate, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate{


   let FieldScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/TesingCampusField.dae")!

let GuyScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Guy.dae")!
//-------------------HUD-SetUp-------------------------------------------------------
let overlayScene = SKScene(size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    scnView.overlaySKScene = overlayScene
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    scnView.scene = FieldScene
    scnView.delegate = self
    scnView.overlaySKScene!.delegate = self
    scnView.overlaySKScene!.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    scnView.overlaySKScene!.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    scnView.overlaySKScene!.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0)
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = false
    scnView.showsStatistics = false

    let Guy1: SCNNode = GuyScene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Bob_014", recursively: true)!
    FieldScene.rootNode.addChildNode(Guy1)

    ButtonA.size = CGSize(width: 6, height: 9)
    ButtonA.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(-13.3, -0.5)
    ButtonA.zPosition = 0
    overlayScene.addChild(ButtonA)

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    //--------------------------
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    FieldScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 5, z: 15)
    //-----------------------------------------------
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
    FieldScene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
    //-----------------------------------------------
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    FieldScene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)
    //----------------------------------------------
}
    func AButtonPressed() {
    let AButtonPressed = SKTexture(imageNamed: "GreenAButtonPressed")
    let OrignalButtonA = SKTexture(imageNamed:"GreenAButton")
    let AButtonPressedAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([AButtonPressed, OrignalButtonA], timePerFrame: 0.2)
    let RunAButtonPressedAnimation = SKAction.repeatAction(AButtonPressedAnimation, count: 1)
    ButtonA.runAction(RunAButtonPressedAnimation)
    print("finishedpressing")
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location1 = touch.locationInNode(self.overlayScene)
        if self.overlayScene.nodeAtPoint(location1) == self.ButtonA {
            AButtonPressed()
            print("AButtonPressed")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your gesture recognizer is configured to call the `handleTap:` method when the user taps the view, but you don't define that method.

```
func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // do something
}
```

If you want to use `touchesBegan` directly, then you don't need the gesture recognizer.